# What to wire ground to?

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-motor, ground

I have a circuit involving a DC motor and voltage regulator as following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fopJU6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What would I realistically wire the ground to? Would it be the negative side of the DC motor or some random hunk of metal? (Side note: am I using the voltage regulator correctly here?)

Comment: @zack1544 the motor only has two leads though.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question the first time. Disregard my last comments

Comment: You connect the ground(of your regulator) to the negative terminal of the battery/power source

Comment: @zack1544 so that would be the negative side of the motor, correct?

Comment: Yes and that too

Comment: Wait let me make a diagram. Just a second

Comment: Good luck on your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:I misread your question for the 2nd time...I was answering it in a rush. I didn't realize that the motor was being used as a generator, and I thought it was the output of the circuit.
Here is a diagram with the capacitors and the correct connections. The diode should be chosen, so that the max motor output voltage minus the diode's forward voltage drop is less than the maximum input voltage of the regulator's input:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fht66q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You could use bigger capacitors if you want

Comment: Is there a limit on the capacitor size?

Comment: Note: The two capacitors don't have to be the same value

Comment: Since you are using a motor, I would be on the safe side and put a larger capacitor on the output(like a 100uf)

Comment: There is no limit, but don't use some huge super-capacitors.

Comment: @GamrCorps. THERE ARE THREE ISSUES WITH THIS CIRCUIT. 1. the LED will not like 5V, he needs a resistor in there, (Since the OP is using the DC motor as a generator) 2. the voltage out could be minus or, 3. if turning fast enough, input voltage can exceed the max input on the regulator.

Comment: @Trevor thanks,I will fix the LED part. I thought the question was that the output is a motor and the input is a 12V power source. I didn't see the word motor next to the voltage source in the question's diagram. Sorry I messed up pretty bad...will fix

Comment: @zack1544 easy miss. I didn't see the "this section will be replaced..."  thing either. I'm still not convinced the whole thing isn't fubar though.

Comment: @GamrCorps the diode on the input of the regulator prevents backwards current, and since it has a constant voltage drop across it, it should be chosen so that: max motor output-diode's forward voltage drop<max regulator input

Comment: @zack1544 "but don't use some huge super-capacitors." those are the most fun kind and nearly always a bad design choice.